# Cannot remove a validator and apply a new one using jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've faced such a problem:

We are using jquery validation plugin to perform client side validations. The script used to initialize the form is generated dynamically. Tho form itself is also generated dynamically using jTemplates and json.

The problem is that i need to reinitialize validation for some input elements and change error placement. I couldn find any method that would reinit validation rules and error placement in the api of the plugin.

I've tried to do something like this:

The following code is executed for several objects.(someUniqueValue is taken from these objects).

```
//removing old rules.
$("input[value='someUniqueValue']").next('input:text').rules('remove');
//I have a hidden field with unique value and an input after it so the code above is ok.

$("#someForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, elementToValidate) {
        var $messageElement = $("[id='theExactFieldToValidate'][value='someUniqueValue']");
        //error placement logic
    },
    rules: {
        "theExactFieldToValidate": {
             required: true,
             maxlength: 25
         }
    }
});
```

Before each input that i want to validate i have the following(i want error messages to be displayed in this span):

```
<span id="validate-theExactFieldToValidate" class="hidden" style="display:block" value="someUniqueValue"></span>
```

after executing the following:

```
$("input[value='someUniqueValue']").next('input:text').rules('remove');
```

The element loses its validation rules but if i try to apply new rules nothing happens.

```
$("input[value='someUniqueValue']").next('input:text').rules()
```

The code above just returns an empty object.

How can i change validation logic and error placement for separate inputs?

Answer (score 0):

can you place your code on jsfiddle. It will be easy to identify the exact issue you are facing with your code.

Meantime, try this out!

```
$("input[value='someUniqueValue']").next('input:text').rules("theExactFieldToValidate",rules)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your validation settings after creating them initially like this:

```
var validator = $("#someForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, elementToValidate) {
        var $messageElement = $("[id='theExactFieldToValidate'][value='someUniqueValue']");
        //error placement logic
    },
    rules: {
        "theExactFieldToValidate": {
             required: true,
             maxlength: 25
         }
    }
});

validator.settings.rules.theExactFieldToValidate.required = false;
```